# Modifier to remesh objects

Tags: modifiers

I remember a modifier which allowed to remesh a object and to choose something like a tree depth. Depth one led to a single cuboid surrounding the whole original mesh. Increasing the depth further the mesh was subdivided in more faces and got closer to the original shape. Can anyone point me to that modifier? I am searching for it now quit a while and just cant find it...

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the "remesh" modifier.
[image]

Comment: Ok thank you. Maybe it is really what I am looking for and just remember the behaviour a little bit different.

Comment: What behaviour are you looking for ? the "octree depth" is the parameter you can tweak to achieve what you asked in your question. I f you want a blocky look remember to set the mode to "blocks"

Comment: Sorry you are right. It was the tool I was looking for, I was just not used to such an ugly mesh, therefore I remembered a even cleaner mesh using that modifier.